# Laravel 7/8. Custom hash driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

I have old database where passwords are hashed by sha3-256. I am creating a new site and i should use old db. But Auth::attempt() use bcrypt(default). How can I set hashing driver sha3-256?

Comment: You could also create a custom auth guard for this, if you don't want to migrate, but I suspect you don't want to keep the legacy hashes forever, docs on that here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Answer (score 3):

Its preferred to use the hashing algorithms that come with Laravel, cause Laravel supports only  Bcrypt and Argon2.

However, to help you migrate to new algorithm, you can in your Users table make a column named *sha3_password*, where you put the old password, and in the login, you make an if statement to check if sha3_password is not null and compare typed-in password with your sha3-256, if it matches, then you update users password field using bcrypt, and set sha3_password to null. That way when ever a user logins, if its his first time, his password would be updated, else log him in normally.

I used this method to migrate a project, and it worked like a charm, my login function was like below, you can use same logic basically :

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        #Update old password after migration to new platform
        $user= User::where('email',request('email'))
            ->where('password_sha1', sha1(request('password')))
            ->where('password', null)
            ->first();
        if($user)
        {
            $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
            $user->password_sha1 = null;
            $user->update();
        }

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password'), 'status' => 1])) {
            // Authentication passed...\
            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
    }
```

Comment: i'd substitute bcrypt with Hash::make(request('password')) to be on the safe side, but this looks helpful!